# In Azure SQL, what is the difference between a standard eDTU and a premium eDTU given it costs significantly more?

Tags: azure-sql-database

Based on [Microsoft's Azure SQL pricing chart](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/) a standard elastic pool of 100 eDTU's costs $223/month, whereas a premium elastic database pool of 125 eDTU's costs $697/month.

Given the almost 3 times price difference, what is the difference between the performance of a standard eDTU and a premium eDTU?

Or am I just paying a higher price for the ability to use more eDTU's for a single database, a larger max database size and longer point-in-time restore?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the higher burst limit per database (1000 instead of 100 eDTU), premium elastic pool tier provides several additional features like

- Active geo replication (ability to set up readonly secondaries)
- Longer point-in-time restore capability
- Premium tier eDTUs also provide significantly higher IO capability compared to standard and basic tiers.

Some distinctions are described in detail [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-service-tiers/?rnd=1)

-- Srini Acharya

Comment: Active geo replication is available in Standard Elastic Pools.
Also, both Premium and Standard offer point-in-time restore going back 35 days.

Answer (score 2):

The primary distinction between Standard pools and Premium elastic pools is the number of eDTUs that any single database in the pool can burst to.  In the case of Standard pools, the burst limit is 100 DTUs, and in the case of Premium pools the burst limit is 1000 DTUs.

Comment: I have S6 at 400DTU, if I upgrade to P1 125DTU.. why am i losing DTUS but yet it cost more?

Comment: Expect premium storage to come online before standard storage when there is an MS data center "issue'.